# Is it possible to get the name of a physical quantity related to a quantity, e.g. watts->power?

Tags: physics, units

Is there a way to get the name of the physical quantity given by a particular unit?  For example, `QuantityUnit[Quantity[1, "Henries"]]` returns `"Henries"`,  but I want to know what `"Henries"` are a measure of.  That is, "electrical inductance".  Will *Mathematica* provide that kind of information?

Comment: You must be wrong. "Henries" has nothing to do with inductance. Try `WolframAlpha["Quantity Henries"]`. The correct answer is obviously "342037 people" :)

Comment: The problem could be also that several physical quantities can be measured in Henries (H). As noted, use W|A...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there isn't a way to do this without W|A but this gives what you are after:

```
WolframAlpha[#, {{"PhysicalQuantity", 1}, 
    "ComputableData"}] & /@ {"Henries", "Meters", "Volts"}
(* {"magnetic inductance", "length", "electric potential difference"} *)
```